# Unable to reverse value for property path "": The choice "" does not exist or is not unique. (Using Select2)

Tags: forms, symfony, tags, entity, jquery-select2

In my application I have a 'Customer' entity as well as a 'CustomerName' entity.

Each Customer can have many CustomerName ($id, $name (string), $isActive(boolean), $customer(the entity))

In my Customer creation form, I have a 'customerName' field which works with select2, here's the code

```
->add('customerNames', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name(s)',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => 'false',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'select2',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                ],
            ])
```

Here's how it looks like (I press enter between each name to create the tag using select2)

[image: select2 input for names]

For the moment, I ensure that each submitted tag is processed in the controller and allows to create as many CustomerName entities as submitted tags.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $names= $form->get('customerNames')->getData();

            foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
                $customerName = new CustomerName();
                $customerName->setName($name);
                $customerName->setCustomer($customer);
```

It worked when I was using the existing CustomerName entities (with the EntityType) but now I'm creating the tags from scratch and I get this error :

```
Unable to reverse value for property path "customerNames": The choice "Name1" does not exist or is not unique.
```

Do u have a solution for this ? :(

Comment: You need to use a `DataTransformer`, see : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html