# Submit Symfony form with dynamics tags created using select2

Tags: forms, symfony, jquery-select2

I have my form using Symfony 5. I can currently create tags dynamically with Select2 in my ChoiceType::class

But I don't use any input already present in the form (I deleted the 'choices' field) because I want the only choices available to be those that the user submits

I encounter this error as soon as I submit the form, any suggestions?

```
Unable to reverse value for property path "userNames": The choice "NameTest" does not exist or is not unique.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to reverse value for property path "": The choice "" does not exist or is not unique. (Using Select2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834807/unable-to-reverse-value-for-property-path-the-choice-does-not-exist-or-is)

Comment: dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834807/unable-to-reverse-value-for-property-path-the-choice-does-not-exist-or-is